# Inserting Value in API with HTTP-Request

Tags: javascript, json, api, http, request

I am using the Package **request**. You can find it in npm. I try several times to add Data in my API. My API is from **myjson.com/api**. I really need help. I try the all methods like put,post,get ... . I just wanna add the Customer into the API. Everytime if the Values of the Object Customer changed, it should create a new line and add this customer to.

For example: You have a website where customer can sign up. And you save every sign up in a new line in your API.

```
var customer = {
    "Customerid": customerID,
    "Sex": sex,
    "Lastname": lastname,
    "Firstname": firstname,
    "State": state,
    "Street": street,
    "Postcode": postcode,
    "Birthdate": birthdate,
    "Email": email,
    "Monthly Earnings": mothEarn
};

var customerData = JSON.stringify(customer);
addCustomerAPI(customerData);



function addCustomerAPI(customerData){
   request({
                url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1efewz",
                type: "PUT",
                data: customerData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(data)
                }
            });


}
```

I hope you guys can help, I am really sad right now.

Best Regards

Michael

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no nothing on the webpage wich i post. Its update the value after I run application but in my application it doesnt work

Comment: Did you import the module in the JS file? @MichaelDev
`var request = require('request')`

Comment: yes its allready implemented

Answer (score 0):

You have issues in the options that you pass to the `request` function. Refer the [request docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) here.

See the code below. I have made changes in the options passed. This would work.

```
var customer = {
  "Customerid": customerID,
  "Sex": sex,
  "Lastname": lastname,
  "Firstname": firstname,
  "State": state,
  "Street": street,
  "Postcode": postcode,
  "Birthdate": birthdate,
  "Email": email,
  "Monthly Earnings": mothEarn
};

addCustomerAPI(customer);

function addCustomerAPI(customer){
  request({
    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1efewz",
    method: "PUT",
    json: customer
  }, function (err, res, body) {
    console.log(body);
  });


}
```

The `customer` JSON can be passed directly without converting it to a string and the callback function is the second parameter to the `request` function.

**NOTE**

Please note that the *update myjson api* will only replace the existing data with the new data that you supply. It won't append the data. If you want to append the data, first you need to fetch the data, then merge them with the new data and update it using the API.

Comment: With merge you mean like an array that save the existing data and add the new data?

Comment: @MichaelDev Yes, first the existing data stored on `myjson api` will be collected and stored in an array. The new data will be appened to this array and the resulting array will be stored to myjson.